# Recursive grep with wildcard and a pattern in the middle

Tags: grep

I have 4 patterns of lines in files, in current directory and subdirectories:

```
type bed
type bed 1
type bed 1 +
type bed 1 .
type bed 2
type bed 2 +
type bed 2 .
```

etc., where the pattern is that the number (1 - 15) after "bed" increases, followed by a "+" or a "." or not followed anything.

I need to corral output for files only with pattern type

```
type bed 1 + 
type bed 2 +
type bed 3 +
```

and I do not want to see files like

```
type bed
type bed 1
type bed 1 .
type bed 2
type bed 2 .
```

etc.

What I've tried:

```
grep -r -E 'type bed [1-15]' *
```

But I can't figure out how to limit my search to only include files that are followed by a "+"

And I need help defining [1-15], as it seems only [1-9] works in that it returns numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. But as soon as I double digit numbers then my results are not what I would expect.

Ideas or links to related posts much appreciated!

Comment: `[1-15]` is the same as `[51-1]` is the same as `[51]` is the same as `[15]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help. `[1-5]?` matches an optional second digit. A `+` escaped by `\` matches a literal `+` at the end

```
grep -r -E 'type bed [0-9][1-5]? \+' *
```